# Fixing some content at the end of first page aspose words java

Tags: java, aspose.words

I am working with apose words java recently.

In my first page I have a table need to merge, which can grow any size, no fixed number of rows and  at the end of my first page, I want to keep some content (for example contact details) to be fixed. (Note: I can't keep contact details in Footer or in foot note section because of some formatting I need to ensure which can't maintain in footer or foot note section)

On growing of table as many rows, My content is going down, But I want to fix it at the end of my first page. if table grows bigger in size, wanted to skip the content and render table in next page.

is there any solution/work around for this?

My expected results are like below....

**Page 1 Start**

dynamic Table row1

dynamic Table row2

dynamic Table row3

**Contact Details ,wanted to fix at the end of my first page**

**Page 1 end**

**Page 2 Start**

dynamic table row 4

dynamic table row 5

........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, ideally the contact details should be set in a footer. It is possible, but very risky.

First create a new document, either in Aspose.Words or MS Word, it will be used as a template.

1. Add a blank table on top
2. Add contact details, after the blank table
3. Add a bookmark, after the contact details

[image: Template document]

Now, using Aspose.Words, you can check the location of the **bookmark**, every time you are adding a new row in the table. If bookmark is at page 1, add new row to the first table. If bookmark is at page 2, add new row to the second table. Below is the sample code that adds rows to the table, keeping the contact details fixed on page 1.

Template document: [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S7uu28AdY0eWtJeE9CYkNsa1U&authuser=1)
Java source code is given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String template = Common.DATA_DIR + "Contact Template.docx";
        String saveDocument = Common.DATA_DIR + "Contact with tables.docx";
        String bookmarkNameContact = "ContactEnd";

        // Load the template
        com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc = new com.aspose.words.Document(template);
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(wordDoc);

        // Find the contacts bookmark
        com.aspose.words.Bookmark bookmarkContact = wordDoc.getRange().getBookmarks().get(bookmarkNameContact);

        // Set the table with null
        com.aspose.words.Table table = null;

        // Add some rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            // If contacts bookmark is on 1st page, add new rows to first table
            if (getBookmarkPage(wordDoc, bookmarkContact) == 1)
            {
                table = (com.aspose.words.Table) wordDoc.getChild(NodeType.TABLE, 0, true);
            } else
            {
                // If the contacts bookmark is on second page, add rows to second table
                table = (com.aspose.words.Table) wordDoc.getChild(NodeType.TABLE, 1, true);
                // If there is no second table, create it
                if (table == null)
                {
                    table = createNewTable(wordDoc, bookmarkContact);
                }
            }

            // Add rows dynamically to either first or second table
            addRow(wordDoc, table, "some text " + i);
        }

        // Save the document
        wordDoc.save(saveDocument);

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private static com.aspose.words.Table createNewTable(com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc, com.aspose.words.Bookmark bookmarkContact) throws Exception
{
    // Get the first table and clone it to create the second one
    com.aspose.words.Table firstTable = (com.aspose.words.Table) wordDoc.getChild(NodeType.TABLE, 0, true);
    com.aspose.words.Table table = (com.aspose.words.Table) firstTable.deepClone(true);

    // Add the second table after the bookmark
    bookmarkContact.getBookmarkEnd().getParentNode().getParentNode().appendChild(table);

    // Delete all its rows
    table.getRows().clear();

    return table;
}

// Add a new row to the table
private static void addRow(com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc, com.aspose.words.Table table, String text)
{
    // Create a new row
    com.aspose.words.Row row = new com.aspose.words.Row(wordDoc);
    row.getRowFormat().setAllowBreakAcrossPages(true);
    // Add it to the table
    table.appendChild(row);
    // Add cells to the row
    for (int iCell = 0; iCell < 4; iCell++)
    {
        // Create a new cell and set text inside it
        com.aspose.words.Cell cell = new com.aspose.words.Cell(wordDoc);
        cell.appendChild(new com.aspose.words.Paragraph(wordDoc));
        cell.getFirstParagraph().appendChild(new Run(wordDoc, text));
        cell.getFirstParagraph().getParagraphFormat().setSpaceAfter(0);

        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
}

private static int getBookmarkPage(com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc, com.aspose.words.Bookmark bookmarkContact) throws Exception
{
    // Find the page number, where our contacts bookmark is
    LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(wordDoc);
    return collector.getStartPageIndex(bookmarkContact.getBookmarkEnd());
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @Saquib, Thanks for your reply. We will try out your solution.